# PHP Find Value in Simple XML Object

Tags: php, xml

I have a PHP Simple XML Object with multiple values in it.

I am trying to target a specific `QID` in the object and find out the corresponding `Role` is.

Example:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [QID] => Q5678
                    [Role] => Super Admin
                )

            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [QID] => Q1234
                    [Role] => Super Admin
                )

        )

)
```

I couldn't really find anything that allowed me to search an object in this fashion like I can in JavaScript.

Would there be a way to say (Psuedo Code) : `getRole('Q1234');` // Output Super Admin

I am able to change the structure of this output if needed but more so looking for verification that I can find this "Needle in a haystack" so to speak.

Comment: `foreach (data)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use custom function. You can use function like as following

```
function find_role($object, $id) {
    foreach ($object->data as $inside_object) {
        if ($id == $inside_object->QID) {
           return $inside_object->Role;
        }
    }
return false;
```

}

It will return you role. You can print it as

```
echo find_role($object, "Q5678");
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Xpath. It is an expression language that allows you to fetch parts of an DOM using location paths (including conditions). In SimpleXML that feature is limited, `SimpleXMLElement::xpath()` will always return an array of SimpleXMLElement objects.

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<roles>
  <data>
    <QID>Q5678</QID>
    <Role>Super Admin</Role>
  </data>
  <data>
    <QID>Q1234</QID>
    <Role>Standard User</Role>
  </data>
</roles>
XML;

$roles = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

var_dump(
  (string)$roles->xpath('//data[QID="Q1234"]/Role')[0]
);
```

Output:

```
string(13) "Standard User"
```

The expression `//data` fetches any `data` element node in the document. `[QID="Q1234"]` is an condition that limits the result to elements with an `QID` child node with the content `Q1234`. Adding `/Role` fetches the `Role` child nodes of that filtered node list.

The result is an array of SimpleXMLElement objects, so you need to fetch the first element of the array and cast it into a string.

In DOM you could fetch the string directly:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);


var_dump(
  $xpath->evaluate('string(//data[QID="Q1234"]/Role)')
);
```